# Undo/revert local changes to PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Say I have a PFObject which I am editing. At later stage I wish to cancel the changes I have done to the PFObject. How do I revert back to original copy of PFObject?

What I have tried

```
    if (self.request.isDirty) {   // self.request is a PFObject
        // Reload object
        NSLog(@"%@", self.request.requestTitle); // Logs ABC, Original was DEF
        [self.request refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", self.request.requestTitle);   // Logs ABC
                [self.requestDetailsTableView reloadData];
            }
        }];
    }
```

I tried fetching the object as well, but same result

```
    if (self.request.isDirty) {   // self.request is a PFObject
        // Reload object
        NSLog(@"%@", self.request.requestTitle); // Logs ABC, Original was DEF
        [self.request fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", self.request.requestTitle);   // Logs ABC
                [self.requestDetailsTableView reloadData];
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Have you saved the PFObject at any point?

Comment: Nope. I did not. Have checked in the database to be sure. I believe if the data is available, it would get it from the cache (which I believe should be the case with fetchIfNeeded likes)

Comment: Perhaps first try clearing the cached result of the PFQuery for that PFObject using `clearCachedResult`: http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/clearCachedResult

Comment: Did you try something like `self.request = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithObjectId:self.request.objectId]` before fetching? Maybe this could help.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a revert method on `PFObject` which will reset your object back to the server state as long as you haven't called save: http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(im)revert

For example, I use a pushed view controller with a form to edit properties on my PFObject subclass and I have two buttons for Cancel and Save...

```
@IBAction override func cancelAction() {
    self.myObject?.revert()
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

@IBAction override func saveAction() {
    self.myObject?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (succeeded) {
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        } else {
            // Show error
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way to do this directly - you need to do a little fancy footwork with your calls :)

Try this:

```
if (self.request.isDirty) {   // self.request is a PFObject
    // Reload object
    NSLog(@"%@", self.request.requestTitle); // Logs ABC, Original was DEF
    PFQuery *newRequest = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourClassName"];
    //Add your request parameters here...

    [newRequest getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) 
            self.request = object;
            NSLog(@"%@", self.request.requestTitle);   // Should log DEF
            [self.requestDetailsTableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I did do things the fancy way. But wanted to post the question hoping that some Parse developer would trip over it and do something about it. And Thanks :)